# Error: "The request could not be completed because the specified solution was not found."

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365

I am trying to upload wsp solution to Office 365 in Solution Gallery but It's throwing error

> Sorry, something went wrong
>
> The request could not be completed because the specified solution was not found.

Same wsp solution is uploading and activating to another site collection and other tenant but not deploying in my root site collection in Office365.

**EDIT:** Even when I am uploading any file to Site Pages library or changing the welcome page of the site, this error occurs.

And even from SharePoint Designer I am unable to change my welcome page and uploading any file to library.

Any solution ?

Comment: May be Microsoft is changing it's policy for custom managed code but it is not fully applicable everywhere. May be due to this, it causes issues.

Comment: There is no managed code in the solution... It's working fine on other tennants & even on same tennant's other site collection..

Comment: That's good. May be microsoft is deprecating the WSP solution on Office 365. It's not wise solution now to use wsp on Office 365. :)

Comment: Yes..Now Code based Sandboxed solutions are no longer available in office 365. So you have to use the add-in model or pure client-side development. Please take a look in this https://dev.office.com/blogs/removing-code-based-sandbox-solutions-in-sharepoint-online

Comment: There is reusable workflow template solution also which is not working. And it's not throwing error on activation but on uploading the solution.

Comment: They did start removing code based sandboxed solutions: https://dev.office.com/blogs/removing-code-based-sandbox-solutions-in-sharepoint-online It most likely is staggered process - they will be doing it in batches of tenants.

Comment: My solution is not Managed Code. And what is the relation between sandbox and changing welcome page of the site ?!!. Even if I am trying to change welcome page or uploading any file on Site Pages then this error is occuring.

Comment: In that case,  since it works on other tenant,  this sounds like a good time to raise a support ticket with Office 365 support :)

Comment: I agree with Cthulhubutt - I've seen this message on some cross-site collection web parts trying to display info from one site collection type to another (eg, from collab site collection to publishing).  If that is what you're trying to do, creating a CSWP would be more effective.  Strange that it is working on another tenant/collection; I would suspect if so, it's the same type of collection on the other tenant.

Answer (score 1):

Verify if you or someone else has registered an event receiver on the Site or List. If the event receivers solution can not be found you would get a message such as yours. In that case your WSP is not the failing file, it is the lingering reference to an event receiver.

Check all eventreceivers and remove the ones that should not be there. Then add the WSP again.